# I cant run my android notification because it comes up as a error

Tags: java, notifications

the emulator wont let me run it as it comes up as a error

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setTicker("Ticker Title")
    .setContentTitle("Content Title")
    .setContentText("Notification content.")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent);

    noti.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti); 
}
```

Comment: Error message could be helpful.

Comment: Hi, you appear to be new to StackOverflow. When you post a question and say you have an error, please make sure you include the error message, the name of the exception, and indicate which line it occurred at. This will assist people that are trying to come up with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of error comes up?
Also, I think you might have forgotten to call build() on your Notification.Builder.